# Python - Implicit Boolean comparisons

Tags: python, boolean, comparison

I was reading the PEP 8 (Python . org), and I noticed that using implicit comparisons with Boolean was preferred.

```
if booleanCond == True     # Actually works
if booleanCond             # Works too but preferred according to PEP8
```

Those two statements mean the same, but in most languages I know explicit comparison is preferred.
Can anyone explain me (quickly ?) why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Imo `==  True` doesn't add any new information so it's just clutter making the code messy

Comment: 1. You should use `is` with booleans rather than `==` 2. What reads more fluently, `if something` or `if something is True` ?

Comment: The two statements are *not* equivalent. Consider the case where `booleanCond` is a nonempty string, for example.

Comment: @Deep `is` with booleans? Wat?!

Comment: If `booleanCond` is a `bool` already, then why not `if ((booleanCond == True) == True) == True`? Because it's silly you say? Well… *yeah*.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I don't get your point, let's assume that _booleanCond_ is not boolean but a string. If it's empty it will be detected as _False_, and as _True_ if it's not empty.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The entire premise of this question is that `booleanCond` is a boolean, not a sting/list/dict/anything else

Comment: @ChristophePeter if `booleanCond` is a string (for example) then `booleanCond == True` will **never** evaluate to `True`, even if `booleanCond` is not empty

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh, I thought. The PEP is quite unclear then. "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."
I supposed that not empty sequences where _True_

Comment: *Falsey* would be the better formulation. That means `bool([])` is `False`. But `[] == False` is `False`. Which makes sense, because, well, an empty list doesn't equal a boolean.

Comment: @ChristophePeter It's clear. The PEP describes what happens only when you use the syntax the PEP describes...

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes but what happens when you try something else ? /o\

Comment: @deceze Ok that's how i should understand it. 
Thanks guys !

Comment: This statement in PEP8 directly contradicts [the second statement of PEP20, "Explicit is better than implicit."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Though I'd also just use the boolean nature of `bool`s myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK explicit comparison is frowned upon in most languages. There is [a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true) about this practice on the Software Engineering stack exchange.

The big picture is that if you need to explicitely compare your boolean condition to `True` you might have a naming problem with your variable.

`if is_blue:` reads well (which is an important thing in python because it helps reduce the cognitive load of the programmer) and `if is_blue is True:` does not.

As usual this is a heuristic and should not be dogmatic, but if you ever feel that you need to compare a boolean value to `True` or `False` to help your reader understand what you're doing it might be worth questionning your naming for this variable.